# Get Simple Product Details Passing Configurable productId and option like color

Tags: magento2

Get Simple Product Details Passing Configurable productId and option like color

Using Product Collection I want to fetch this.

Answer (score 1):

Used Following code to fetch the details

```
  $superAttribute = [$color_id => $sel_propduct_color];
    $childProduct   = $product->getTypeInstance()->getProductByAttributes($superAttribute, $product);
    $child_product_id = $childProduct->getID();
```